# How do I rename my dataframe if there are spacings and numbers in it? pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are spacings and numbers inside some of the rows of my dataframe. For example Florida16, Florida19, Wisconsin (State of)
I want to remove those extra numbers and spacings and just keep the main names
How do I this with rename? Do I need a for loop?

df.rename()

Comment: you need to use regex and .str.replace("16", "") for removing this

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.array([['Florida19','test with space', 'AnotherNumber18'],['Florida19','test with space', 'AnotherNumber18 andspace']])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
patterns = ['[0-9]+', '\s.*']
replacement = ''
df.replace(patterns, replacement, regex=True, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

This results in:

```py
         0     1             2
0 Florida  test  AnotherNumber
1 Florida  test  AnotherNumber
```

**Edit:**

If the desired output for an entry e.g. `Wisconsin (State of)` should be `Wisconsin(Stateof)` (or in general just a removement of whitespace) then use `patterns = ['[0-9]+','\s']`

This will result in:

```py
         0              1                     2
0  Florida  testwithspace          AnotherNumber
1  Florida  testwithspace  AnotherNumberandspace
```

**For index:**

If you have these values set as "index" of your DataFrame like:

```py
                                      1                           2
0                                                              
Florida19             'test with space'           'AnotherNumber18'
Florida16             'test with space'  'AnotherNumber18 andspace'
Wisconsin (State of)            'info1'                     'info2'
```

You can use `df.rename()` with regular expressions to change these indices:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

data = np.array([['Florida19','test with space', 'AnotherNumber18'],
                 ['Florida16','test with space', 'AnotherNumber18 andspace'],
                 ['Wisconsin (State of)', 'info1', 'info2']])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index(0, inplace=True)

pattern1 = r'[0-9]+|\s.*'  # match numbers or string parts that start with a whitespace
pattern2 = r'[0-9]+|\s'  # for only removing numbers and whitespaces

df1 = df.rename(index=(lambda x: re.sub(pattern1,'',x))
df2 = df.rename(index=(lambda x: re.sub(pattern2,'',x))
```

This will produces:

```py
df1 =
                           1                           2
0                                                   
Florida    'test with space'           'AnotherNumber18'
Florida    'test with space'  'AnotherNumber18 andspace'
Wisconsin            'info1'                     'info2'

df2 =
                                    1                           2
0                                                            
Florida             'test with space'           'AnotherNumber18'
Florida             'test with space'  'AnotherNumber18 andspace'
Wisconsin(Stateof)            'info1'                     'info2'
```

Comment: The expected output is not "test" but "testwithspace". Second row it should be "AnotherNumberandspace". I think the pattern `'\s.*'` is the error and this should be `' '` . Could you check this?

Comment: Ok, then it was a misunderstanding. Thought the output for `Wisconsin (State of)` should result in only `Wisconsin`.